# TYPO3 Where is "Alias" field?

Tags: alias, typo3

According to the TYPO3 manual:

> Where is the Alias field?
>
> Alias field in TYPO3 page properties The Alias field can be found in
>   the page properties. Here it is located on the so-called "second
>   options palette", which is not visible by default. To show this
>   palette, you need to check the "Show secondary options (palettes)"
>   checkbox at the bottom of the page properites form.
>
> In recent TYPO3 versions (eg.. 4.5.2) the Alias field is located in
>   the page properties, tab "Behaviour" and is called "URL Alias".

Here's a screenshot from the page properties how I see them:

[image: Alias]

But where is the "Alias" field in the version we are using? (TYPO3 Ver. 4.5.19).

Even if I put the Type of the page to "Advanced" instead of "Standard". I get a lot more tabs, but not the "Behaviour" tab. In the access list of the user group, everything is checked and the user has full admin rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your properties form on the screenshot lacks many common fields and tabs, apparently you logged in as a common admin without access to it. (see typical form (4.6.x) for compression)

[image: full view]

Log in as a full admin and check if these fields are available.

If not that means, they where disabled with PageTS/UserTS

If they are available for full admin and you need/want to enable them for common editors as well you need edit `access lists` of the editor's group and by selecting proper `Allowed excludefields`

Comment: We have one user in the system who has full admin rights. In the access list for his group, everything is checked.

Comment: So they were disabled with PageTS/UserTS. How do I re-enable them? The typo3 manual is leaving me very confused.

Comment: Just remove from the PageTS and or UserTS lines that hides it. By default fields are enabled.

Comment: Stupid question incoming: Where would I do that? I can see a textfield "TSconfig" in the Options tab. Is that where I type something in order to make the Behaviour tab visible or... ? (If so: what do I type there?)

Comment: If there are no lines which hides it, you don't need to add anything, as I wrote, fields are ENABLED in TS by default. In such case check PageTS of some 'higher' page, also check the user's TS and/or group's TS if there are no lines like `TCEFORM.tablename.fieldname.disabled = 1`

Answer (score 1):

It might also be worth noticing that there is a difference between the "Live" and "Draft" workspace. It may not show up in the Draft workspace whereas it does show in the Live workspace. Just noticed this recently.